# Changes in local gem does not show in the application in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a gem for my application and want to see if my gem is working on a real application or not, but the problem is if I want to see the changes in the application I have to restart the server.

I have googled the issue but all the solutions were either not working or relatively old (backing to rails 3 or so); is there any way to see the changes without restarting the server in rails 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can because Gems are initialized when you start the server. Any change to the gemfile or gems themselves will require a server restart. The same is true about Routes, Config, etc.